# gem install/update fails with "no implicit conversion of nil into String"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

Using rvm, anytime I try to install or update a gem (or rubygems), I get the same error:

```
$ gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-2.6.6.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

My system ruby however, works fine.

Comment: There is not enough data to suggest anything. Please at least post the whole error message (and try `gem install rubygems-update` and post the result here as well.)

Comment: That is the entire error message. The next line is the terminal prompt. `gem install rubygems-update` has the same error.

Comment: Try `which gem` and `which ruby` and see the results. If you have a system Ruby installed by your distribution package, maybe you are trying to update it, and this won't work.

Comment: `$which gem` > `/Users/davbeck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/gem`. `$which ruby` > `/Users/davbeck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby`. I get this problem on all rvm versions, but not the system ruby (OS X 10.11.5)

Comment: After all, I would suggest you to `rm -rf ~/.rvm` and reinstall everything from the scratch from http://rvm.io

Comment: I've done the several times.

Answer (score 14):

This is a bug in the ruby gem installer of version 2.5.x. Patch the file installer.rb (on my machine in /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb) as follows:

Replace:

```
if ruby_executable then
      question << existing
```

With:

```
if ruby_executable then
      question << (existing || 'an unknown executable')
```

Comment: Worked for me, a, after using `sudo gem --debug update --system` I found out the place of installer.rb on my High Sierra Mac:
```/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/installer.rb```

Answer (score 3):

`sudo dnf -y remove ruby\*
sudo find /usr -name "*ruby*" -exec rm -fr {} \; 
sudo dnf install -y ruby 
sudo gem update --system`

works for me, probably a **rubygems** directory removal `failed`

PS : I'm on `fedora` but this should work on `ubuntu` / `debian` by using **apt-get** instead of **dnf**

Comment: I use this method on `ubuntu` and it's work! To be precise, only delete files in `/usr/local` is enough.

Comment: Worked for cygwin (replacing remove/install via dnf with setup-x86.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Set the version manually:

```
gem update --system 2.6.6
```

Comment: How on the Earth that would help?

Comment: All the Google results recommend this, but every version I try, including this one, gives me the same error message.

Comment: So, try to remove your ruby version using:
rvm remove 2.2.1 --archive --gems

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to install xcodeproj. I could not solve it by using gem update (I got the same error).

I solved it by upgrading ruby from version 2.4.0 to 2.5.0_2

```
#brew upgrade ruby
```

After the ruby upgrade gem was updated from version 2.5.2 to version 2.7.6